# Eloquent Eager Load Double Relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

This one's been bothering me and Google hasn't been of any help. I have two models, a Dance model and an Author model. The relationship is that an author can have many dances. The wrinkle is that there are actually two relationships between these objects, as there is the original author and an author much later credited with reconstructing the dance (these are historical dances, after all). I can eager load with the `load()` function for the relation that uses the normal foreign key, but I cannot find out how to eager load the relation that uses a differently-named foreign key.

How do I do eager loading on this second relation?

Comment: you'll have to post your code, for anyone to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting up a relationship with a different foreign key you have to specify in the relationship which key you wanna use...`return $this->hasOne('Author', 'foreign-key');`

So if I understand your question you wanna setup a relationship to two authors, in the same author table....

So maybe something like this then?? (replace `foreign_key` with your table field)

```
public function orig_author(){
 return $this->hasOne('Author');
}

public function second_author(){
 return $this->hasOne('Author', 'foreign-key');
}

public function dance(){
return $this->hasMany('Dance');
}
```

Then just retrieve it like so...`($id being the id of your dance)`

```
$dance = Dance::with('orig_author','second_author')->find($id);
```

But to be honest, I've never tried having a double relationship with a table.....let me know if it works out for you. :)  Id be very interested.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I'm testing it, but I don't want to accept the answer, at least without either confirmation or some notes on how the real solution ends up slightly differently until I have _confirmed_ a working syntax. So far, though, it looks good.

Comment: Finally got to a point where I can definitively test this. Yes, this is working for me. I had misunderstood the documentation for `with()` to be that you provide it with the model name(s), where in reality you give it the function names that return the relationships.

Note: Your example should be updated to be "public function orig_author" instead of "public class orig_author". ;)

Comment: Glad its working for you :)....but wow I cant believe I missed that class/function thing......lol

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$dance = ModelName::query()
    ->with('eagerNameOne')
    ->with('eagerNameTwo')
    ->find($id);
```

where `::query()` was added only tu put all the *eagers* on the same identation level.